# Can I combine these two #update_all lines into one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a migration that does the following:

```
Event.update_all 'tom_cancelled = false', 'tom_cancelled IS NULL'
Event.update_all 'jerry_cancelled = false', 'jerry_cancelled IS NULL'
```

Can (and if I can, how do) I combine these together to dry it up? Would I use a block?

Comment: You can't. They're different statements with different conditions, meant to apply to different records.

Comment: You can pack them into `CASE` statements, but what you already have is probably the appropriate way in Rails.  `UPDATE tbl SET tom_cancelled = CASE WHEN tom_cancelled IS NULL then FALSE ELSE tom_cancelled END, jerry_cancelled = CASE WHEN jerry_cancelled IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE jerry_cancelled END;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless you want to use a loop in ActiveRecord, but it doesn't make sense because you'll end up with one `UPDATE` query for every record in the result set + 1 for the SELECT.

In the current way, you only run two queries, no matter how many records are in the result set.

There is definitely no need to abstract more the current code. Especially considering it runs within a migration.